# How to measure Weblogic avg/max memory and cpu utilization for a specific period of time?

Tags: memory-management, weblogic, monitoring, cpu-usage

My requirement is to measure avg&max consumption of memory and cpu while running a particular workflow on weblogic server. I have considered some tools like jvusualvm & ProcessExplorer but they are giving cpu and memory consumption at that particular moment. 
Is there any tool or weblogic feature where i can see the details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Mission Control and the Flight Recorder feature can help capture the performance of the JVM for a given recorded session - CPU, Memory, etc. JMC is available for use if you have a license for Weblogic or Java SE Advanced.  It's a pretty great value add tool for monitoring and troubleshooting.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html